Does a topological sorting algorithm exist, that is stable on induced subgraphs
I now that topological orderings are not unique.
But I wonder whether are exists an algorithm that sorts DAG nodes by topological order and is stable on induced subgraphs.
What I means by that is that given nodes $a \leq b$ in the sorting in $G$, then for every subgraph $G' \subseteq G$ that contains $a,b$, $a \leq b$ when sorting $G'$.
If it makes it easier you can assume that the nodes already have some arbitrary total order.

Any sorting algorithm can be made stable by replacing $A[x] = y$ with $A[x] = (y, x)$ and sorting by pairs.  It's just not an in place transform which is why it isn't done by default.

@DanielV That's a different sense of "stable".

No topological sorting algorithm is stable in this sense.
Consider the following three directed graphs:

$D_1$, with nodes $\{x,y\}$ and no arcs.
$D_2$, with nodes $\{x,y,z\}$ and arcs $\{x \to z, z \to y\}$.
$D_3$, with nodes $\{x,y,z\}$ and arcs $\{y \to z, z \to x\}$.

Our algorithm must give $D_2$ and $D_3$ their unique topological orders $x < z < y$ and $y<z<x$, respectively. It must also give some topological order for $D_1$: either $x<y$ or $y<x$. Whichever one it chooses will be inconsistent with either the topological order chosen for $D_2$ or the topological order chosen for $D_3$.
(It does not matter if the algorithm knows and makes use of some total order on the set $\{x,y,z\}$. The only assumption here is that the topological order chosen for $D_1$ is only determined by the nodes and arcs of $D_1$, and not on what other graphs we might look at later.)
